# char.IsLetterOrDigit equivalent in php

Tags: php, char

What's the equivelent of `char.IsLetterOrDigit()` in php 5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`ctype_alnum`](http://php.net/ctype_alnum)

Comment: +1 for referencing ctype. I've been using PHP for years and never even knew that extension existed, let alone enabled by default.